# What does a slash before the variable in an IF statement in Windows batch cause?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

I have to adapt an old batch script and there is a `/` in front of the variable name in many `if` commands.

```bat
if /%error_found% == /0 (
  ...
)
```

What is the difference if one use the slash or not. The statement works for me even without slash.

```bat
if %error_found% == 0 (
  ...
)
```

Are there cases where the slash makes a difference?

Comment: Is it used with string comparisons as well? Were these scripts written for "modern" Cmd or were they written for MS-DOS? (I thought I knew a possible reason why the strings are often prefixed, but since spikey_richie mentioned that 'if' has flags, using a slash would actually be counter-productive to that...)

Comment: the scripts are certainly at least 10 years old.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me like a syntax error in string comparison that should have been:
`/%error_found%/ == /0/`.

Better syntax would use quotes:
`"%error_found%" == "0"`
Or parenthesis:
`(%error_found%) GEQ (0)`.

Your syntax of `%error_found% == 0` will only work if `%error_found%`
does not contain a blank and is not empty.

For more information see the
[IF command](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html).